# "dispatch is not a function at onSubmit" after clicking submit button

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

After entering the text in input field and clicking submit button the error occurs: Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function
    at onSubmit

Connecting state and props seems to be correct.

What could be wrong?

```
  */TODOLIPUT*/
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {addTodo} from '../actions/index'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'


let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

    return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!input.value.trim()) {
          return
        }
        dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
        input.value = ''
      }}>
        <input ref={node => {
          input = node
        }} />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: state.todos
  }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({addTodo: addTodo}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(AddTodo)

/*TODOLIST*/
import React from 'react';
import {Todo} from './todo';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'

const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo {...todo} />
    )}
  </ul>
)

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        todos:state.todos
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(TodoList)



/* REDUCER */
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';


export const reducers = combineReducers({
    todos:todos
})



export function todos(state=[], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    text:text,
                    completed:false
                }
            ]
        default:
        return state
    }
} 

*/ACTION*/
export const addTodo = (text) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    text
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make two changes to get your code working.

**First**: If you use `dispatch` in your component, you need not use `mapDispatchToProps` since dispatch will be made available to you by default by `connect`

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AddTodo)
```

**Second**: The other way is to make use of bindActionCreators which binds your action creators to dispatch and hence there is not need for a separate dispatch event in your component

```
let AddTodo = (props) => {
  let input

    return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!input.value.trim()) {
          return
        }
        props.addTodo(input.value);
        input.value = ''
      }}>
        <input ref={node => {
          input = node
        }} />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

One more thing,since your are resolvind the props to `{dispatch}` in your `AddTodo` argument, you wont be having access to the `todos` state.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `dispatch`, since you have used `bindActionCreators` in your `mapDispatchToProps` .

`bindActionCreators` is a helper that enables action creators to directly dispatch actions. So you can just invoke your action creator and it should automatically dispatch the action.

You can either use `dispatch` and not pass `mapDispatchToProps`, or you can use the props injected by `mapDispatchToProps`, and not use `dispatch`. This is why `mapDispatchToProps` is called this way—it lets you define some other props based on dispatch so you don’t need to use it again.

Check this: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examples